# Windows Azure Platform Training Kit - Ive installed it but cannot find it?

Tags: azure

I've installed the November release of the Windows Azure Platform Training Kit from [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396) URL.
I know it installed a whole bunch of bits including about 75 labs via Web Express but I cannot find the entry point to the kit anywhere.

The instructions helpfully state:

> After the content is extracted, the starting page for the traning kit
> will be displayed in your default browser. You can then browse through
> the individual hands-on labs, demos, and presentations.

Which might have been fine the first time it was run but what about the second time? Should there be a link of some sort on my start menu? All i have are a slew of new start menu entries nicely scattered all aboout the place but none of which has any entry point to what was installed last night?

**UPDATE:**

All I have is this:

[image]

My location is different because that's the way that i set it up but other than that there is nothing "training kit" like about. The folders do have content but in what order am i supposed to progress through that content. I was expecting a progression from "Hello World" to "World Domination" but all i have is a bunch of random examples.... and for that i could just as well use the net.

Answer (score 3):

It typically gets extracted to a directory like `C:\WAPTK` if you don't change it. Then you simply open default.htm and allow blocked content.

EDIT: This is what the directory listing should look like:
[image: screenshot of directory listing]

For each lab, there's a document and begin/end files. Also, there's a Setup cmd for each lab.

Comment: Yes that's how it typically is for other kits and examples and what i expected. Please see my update for what i do have. Im setting aside 3 days next week to burn through as much guidance as i can soak up so I really want some structure to the time in order to use it to maximum effect.

Comment: Did you grab the full download or the WebPI version (which is a Preview)? Your directory listing above is missing key html files, which means it didn't install correctly. If you haven't grabbed the full ~300MB file, that's what to grab and install. If that's what you did initially, maybe try a shorter path or a path without underscores or something. I've installed every single training kit and don't recall a single extraction issue.